# aggregating class Date columns in data.table returns non-empty NAs. R

Tags: r, date, data.table, aggregate, na

I've got a data.table dt with a few Date columns. when I aggregate the table, I get NA values for some entries. This is expected. However, the field is actually not NA, even though it shows that it is NA. when I compare those NA Date fields I don't get NA as it would be expected. It's a strange result that I don't understand and it's causing havoc in my analysis.

```
> dt <- data.table(cust = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3)
                 , DTE_off = as.Date(c('2018-07-31', '2019-05-06', '2014-06-01', '2015-06-01', '2019-05-06', '2018-06-18', '2019-05-06'), '%Y-%m-%d')
                 , chp_start = as.Date(c('2001-01-22', '2001-01-22', '2000-01-01', '2000-01-01', '2000-01-01', '2000-01-01', '2000-01-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
                 , chp_end = as.Date(c('2019-05-05', '2019-05-05', '2019-05-05', '2019-05-05', '2019-05-05', '2019-05-05', '2019-05-05'), '%Y-%m-%d')
                 , prod_any = c('Y','Y','Y','Y', 'Y','N','N')) 

> dt
   cust    DTE_off  chp_start    chp_end prod_any
1:    1 2018-07-31 2001-01-22 2019-05-05        Y
2:    1 2019-05-06 2001-01-22 2019-05-05        Y
3:    2 2014-06-01 2000-01-01 2019-05-05        Y
4:    2 2015-06-01 2000-01-01 2019-05-05        Y
5:    2 2019-05-06 2000-01-01 2019-05-05        Y
6:    3 2018-06-18 2000-01-01 2019-05-05        N
7:    3 2019-05-06 2000-01-01 2019-05-05        N
> dt[, month := format(DTE_off, '%Y-%m')]
> dt
   cust    DTE_off  chp_start    chp_end prod_any   month
1:    1 2018-07-31 2001-01-22 2019-05-05        Y 2018-07
2:    1 2019-05-06 2001-01-22 2019-05-05        Y 2019-05
3:    2 2014-06-01 2000-01-01 2019-05-05        Y 2014-06
4:    2 2015-06-01 2000-01-01 2019-05-05        Y 2015-06
5:    2 2019-05-06 2000-01-01 2019-05-05        Y 2019-05
6:    3 2018-06-18 2000-01-01 2019-05-05        N 2018-06
7:    3 2019-05-06 2000-01-01 2019-05-05        N 2019-05
> dt_agg <- dt[ ,.(last_dte_off = max(DTE_off), any_start = max(chp_start[which(prod_any == "Y")], na.rm = TRUE), any_end = max(chp_end[which(prod_any == "Y")], na.rm = TRUE)) , by = .(cust, month)]
Warning messages:
1: In max.default(numeric(0), na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In max.default(numeric(0), na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In max.default(numeric(0), na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
4: In max.default(numeric(0), na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

when I check for NAs in dt_agg, there is none. but when I look at the data, there are NA's. These NA's are valid (they should be there!)

```
> anyNA(dt_agg)
[1] FALSE
> dt_agg
   cust   month last_dte_off  any_start    any_end
1:    1 2018-07   2018-07-31 2001-01-22 2019-05-05
2:    1 2019-05   2019-05-06 2001-01-22 2019-05-05
3:    2 2014-06   2014-06-01 2000-01-01 2019-05-05
4:    2 2015-06   2015-06-01 2000-01-01 2019-05-05
5:    2 2019-05   2019-05-06 2000-01-01 2019-05-05
6:    3 2018-06   2018-06-18       <NA>       <NA>
7:    3 2019-05   2019-05-06       <NA>       <NA>
```

Worse, when I try to to compare the aggregated date fields in dt_agg, the entries that have NA should return NA, but they actually return a value. which means technically they are not NA. I'm not sure what's going on.

```
> dt_agg[, compare := any_start > any_end]
> dt_agg
   cust   month last_dte_off  any_start    any_end compare
1:    1 2018-07   2018-07-31 2001-01-22 2019-05-05   FALSE
2:    1 2019-05   2019-05-06 2001-01-22 2019-05-05   FALSE
3:    2 2014-06   2014-06-01 2000-01-01 2019-05-05   FALSE
4:    2 2015-06   2015-06-01 2000-01-01 2019-05-05   FALSE
5:    2 2019-05   2019-05-06 2000-01-01 2019-05-05   FALSE
6:    3 2018-06   2018-06-18       <NA>       <NA>   FALSE  # what's going on here?!? compare should be NA, not FALSE
7:    3 2019-05   2019-05-06       <NA>       <NA>   FALSE  # what's going on here?! compare should be NA, NOT FALSE
```

I think this has something to do with Date class in aggregate. But still, seeing NA values that are not NA are a bit absurd?

Comment: Issue happens when there is no "Y" for a particular combination (cust = 3)  How do you want to deal with those cases

Comment: If you want to return NA for those cases `dt[, .(last_dte_off = max(DTE_off), any_start = if(!any(prod_any == "Y")) NA_real_ else max(chp_start[which(prod_any == "Y")], na.rm = TRUE)), by = .(cust, month)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is not related to `NA`s in the data, but a particular group doesn't have the 'prod_any' value as "Y", and when we wrap `which` on those, it gives something similar to

```
which(c(1, 3) == 5)
#integer(0)
```

and the `max` of which gives warning

```
max(which(c(1, 3) == 5), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] -Inf
```

> Warning message: In max(which(c(1, 3) == 5), na.rm = TRUE) :   no
>   non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

---

To avoid the warning, we can skip the `max` on those groups by wrapping with an `if/else condition

```
dt[, .(last_dte_off = max(DTE_off),
        any_start = if(!any(prod_any == "Y")) NA_real_ # changed here
              else max(chp_start[which(prod_any == "Y")], na.rm = TRUE),
         any_end = if(!any(prod_any == "Y")) NA_real_  
              else max(chp_end[which(prod_any == "Y")], na.rm = TRUE)),
         by = .(cust, month)]
#   cust   month last_dte_off  any_start    any_end
#1:    1 2018-07   2018-07-31 2001-01-22 2019-05-05
#2:    1 2019-05   2019-05-06 2001-01-22 2019-05-05
#3:    2 2014-06   2014-06-01 2000-01-01 2019-05-05
#4:    2 2015-06   2015-06-01 2000-01-01 2019-05-05
#5:    2 2019-05   2019-05-06 2000-01-01 2019-05-05
#6:    3 2018-06   2018-06-18       <NA>       <NA>
#7:    3 2019-05   2019-05-06       <NA>       <NA>
```

No warnings here

Comment: thanks @akrun. that solves my issue. the "not real" NA is very confusing. why does it even exist?! (perhaps a rhetorical question)